# How to plot a gnuplot using c++ (Xcode) from a csv text file

Tags: c++, xcode, gnuplot

I would like to ask how to plot data that is stored in a text file in CSV format. I am using Xcode and I am looking to do this in C++. The text file being generated is being written to from cURL and I would like to plot said data against time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to use the command:
`set datafile separator ","`
before plotting your file

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will be using the command you mentioned for the CSV but do you know how I could initiate the plot using C++? In terminal it is simply `gnuplot plot(x)` what would be the equivalent for a basic plot in Xcode?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know about Xcode, I can't help you on that. I didn't see that you were working with Xcode. I thought that was just Gnuplot / C++. Maybe you can look for gnuplot's script